# Why don't I have to specify when to scale down with ECS auto-scaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

Consider the following config for auto-scaling ECS:

```
{
  "PolicyName": "test-memory-scaling-policy",
  "ServiceNamespace": "ecs",
  "ResourceId": "service/test/test",
  "ScalableDimension": "ecs:service:DesiredCount",
  "PolicyType": "TargetTrackingScaling",
  "TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration": {
    "TargetValue": 70,
    "PredefinedMetricSpecification": {
      "PredefinedMetricType": "ECSServiceAverageMemoryUtilization"
    },
    "ScaleOutCooldown": 300,
    "ScaleInCooldown": 300,
    "DisableScaleIn": false
  }
}
```

It launches a new task once the average memory utilisation reaches 70%, up to 5 tasks.

It doesn't make sense to me. Imagine I have one task running. Average memory utilisation is 71%. Once a new task is deployed, I guess the average will drop down to 35-40%, then it will have to scale down. But if it does scale down, the average will be 71% again, and it will be stuck in an infinite loop.

How does scale down works if I don't have to specify when to do it then?

Answer (score 2):

Target tracking policy handles scale out and scale in based on metric choose and target value.

You can check CloudWatch alarm it creates to get more insight on each defined value and the amount of data points.

Also Target tracking is fast to scale out but slow to scale in, exactly to avoid the situation you mentioned.

Please check documentation below:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-autoscaling-targettracking.html